# JSON object with Jest tests in node.js project not being parsed properly

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, jestjs, stringify

I have an object with the following interface:

```
export interface range {
  max: number,
  min: number
}
```

That I'm returning from a GET call - the function that is called is listed below.

```
export async function testHandler() {
  let result : range = {
    min: 101, 
    max: 202
  };
 
  return {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: result
    }),
    statusCode: 200
  };
}
```

The idea is that I want to return & parse an instance of the range object to my Jest tests, which are shown below:

```
import {  testHandler, range } from "..";

describe("TestEnv", () => {
  const expectedResponseShape = {
    body: expect.any(String),
    statusCode: expect.any(Number)
  };
 
describe("Test Range Test", () => {
it("should return the correct data shape: min and max, >= 0", async () => {
  const response = await testHandler();
  //make sure we're getting a response with an HTTP body
  expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponseShape);
  expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);

  let r : range = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body));
  expect(r).not.toBeUndefined();

  console.log(`range: ${r}`);
  console.log(`range.min: ${r.min}`);
  console.log(`range.max: ${r.max}`);


  for(var propName in r) {
    if(r.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        console.log(`propname ${propName} =:  ${r[propName]}`);   
    }
  }
});
```

});

So this is where things get really weird. For the life of me I can't figure out why the `r` object won't parse. The output from the logs is below:

```
Test Range Test
      ✓ should return the correct data shape: min and max, >= 0 (46ms)

  console.log 
          range: {"data":{"min":101,"max":202}}

  console.log 
    range.min: undefined

  console.log 
    range.max: undefined

  console.log 
    propname 0 =:  {

  console.log 
    propname 1 =:  "

  console.log 
    propname 2 =:  d

  console.log 
    propname 3 =:  a

  console.log 
    propname 4 =:  t

  console.log 
    propname 5 =:  a
```

and so on until

```
 console.log 
    propname 25 =:  2

  console.log 
    propname 26 =:  0

  console.log 
    propname 27 =:  2

  console.log 
    propname 28 =:  }

  console.log 
    propname 29 =:  }
```

So the data of the object (which is `{min: 101, max:202}` ) seems to be coming in ok, but does not seem to be parsed properly.
What I would like is a final object in the tests that will be able to read a result `r` of type `range`, and be able to read its properties with `r.min` and `r.max`.

The answer is probably obvious, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the "range" is in the `data` prop, and not directly in the `body` of the response.

Secondly you do `JSON.stringify` on the `response.body` which is already a string.

So, use

```
let r : range = JSON.parse(response.body).data;
```

---

the weird logs are also due to the extra `JSON.stringify` of the `response.body`. Your `r` ends up being a string and the `for .. in` is iterating it as an array of chars.